# Solution of a fourth degree equation

Tags: quartics

Is there a viable strategy to solve the following equation in an analytic way, without using numeric methods?

$(1+\frac{1}{8}x^2)^2=\frac{p^2}{2}(\sqrt{1+x^2}+1)$

**Edit:** When I substitute $t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, I get:

$\frac{1}{64}(49+14t^2+t^4)=\frac{p^2}{2}(t+1)$

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat But didn't you forget the square root in there? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Try to substitute $$t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did that and the result seems to be a quartic equation where the term with $t^3$ is missing. But is there a way to solve that type of equation? I'll edit my question to show what I got when I did the substitution you suggested.

Comment: The quartic equation is the best what you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, using $t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, you end with
$$t^4+14 t^2-32 p^2 t-(32 p^2-49)=0$$ which can be solved using [Ferrari's method](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari's_Method).

If you use the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), you should find that
$$\Delta=-1048576\, p^4 \left(p^2-1\right) \left(27 p^2+98\right)$$ which is negative if $p^2 \lt 1$.

We also get $P=112$, $Q=-256 p^2$, $\Delta_0=784-384 p^2$, $D=-2048 p^2$ and you can analyze the number and nature of roots depending on $p$. Now, play with the radicals (have fun) and come back to $x$ (more fun).

Personally, I would prefer to consider the function

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{8}\right)^2}{2 \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1\right)}$$ which is symmetric and shows a minimum value equal to $\frac 14$ at $x=0$. This means that if $p^2 \lt \frac 14$ no root at all; if $p^2 = \frac 14$, a quadruple root equal to $0$ and if $p \gt \frac 14$, two real roots (good to know that they are symmetric) and  two complex conjugate  roots.

If you do not want to play with nasty radicals, just use a numerical method considering that you look for the zero of function
$$g(y)=\frac{\left(1+\frac{y}{8}\right)^2}{2 \left(\sqrt{y+1}+1\right)}-p^2$$

If you consider Newton method, series expansion built at $x=0$ or $x\to \infty$ followed by series reversion will give quite good estimates.